# Using Cassandra to count events based on a time window

Tags: cassandra

I have millions of users {U1,U2,...} in my system and there can be an event E(U,t) associated with any of the users at any moment of time: E(Ui,ti). I store event information in a column family.

```
 UserId1:
       TimeUUID:""
       TimeUUID:""
 UserId2:
       TimeUUID:""
       TimeUUID:""
 etc ...
```

Given current time T, I would like to find two users: with the highest event counts within one hour and two hours. Basically, I want to know the most eventful users provided a certain time constrain.

My solution would involve creating two column families one called `Tminus1` and the other one `Tminus2`. These column families have identical data written to them but the TTL(time to live) differs: one is 1 hour and the other one is 2 hours.

Three is a job that runs all the time and counts columns for each of the rows in both tables and writes results to a new table called "EventStats" that has only two rows:

```
max1hour:
     5609837: user376484, TTL = 1 hour
     4577374: user293760, TTL = 1 hour
     .... 
max2hour:
     4837301: user933734, TTL = 2 hour
     0043746: user948348, TTL = 2 hour
     ....
```

(column name here the count. An issue here is that what will happen if two users have the same counts ... )

When a service wants to know the winning users it just reads the first column from the corresponding rows.

My issue with this solution (even if it is viable) is that it is too cumbersome. Perhaps I am not familiar with some other Cassandra tools that would allow solving this problem in a much more elegant way. Plus, I would like to be able to dynamically introduce and vary more statistical measures like highest even counters within 12 hours, 5 hours etc... this will require creating a new column families similar to `Tminus1` etc.

I contemplated using standard Cassandra counters to avoid writing a counting job but I don't think I can automatically update counters when some columns are removed due to their TTL.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your description that you don't need this information in real time, as you already have a separate process that produces your desired results.  Given this, I think it may make sense to have an external aggregator (perhaps something like [Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/) or [Storm](http://storm-project.net/)) that will produce your statistics and write them back to Cassandra.  You could also use a Hadoop MapReduce job to do this.